# upload rails app to live server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload

how do i go about uploading a rails app that works locally (on MAMP) to a live server?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous solutions. The most common one is using [capistrano](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Capistrano), but you could find some hosting solution with their own deployment process like [Heroku](http://heroku.com/).

Rails guides on the subject: http://rubyonrails.org/deploy